# Week number for first week of Jan not showing in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following data structure:

[image]

Then I have used the following Tableau function to convert week number and year to first day of the week:
`DATE(DATETRUNC('week',DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([year_axis]))))`

Issue, is that when it gets to week 1 and year 2021, instead of showing the week 04/01/2021, it aggregates this data to the last week of December (28/12/2020).

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending upon your locale, tableau starts a week either on Sunday or a Monday.  Moreover, if a first day of a year is not Monday, then the dates before first Monday are considered as week 0 of that year.

Use of this calculation is suggested in this case (for newer versions of tableau desktop)

```
DATE(DATETRUNC('week',
IF ISOWEEKDAY(DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))) =1
then DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))
else DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number]+1)+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))
END
))
```

For those versions of tableau where `ISOWEEKDAY` is not listed, the following calculation is suggested

```
DATE(DATETRUNC('week',
IF DATEPART('weekday', DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))) =1
then DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))
else DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number]+1)+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))
END
))
```

If first day of Year is Monday then `your calculated field` otherwise `week+1`.

See the screenshot where both calculations are compared.  (Note for year 2018)

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: is ISOWEEKDAY a typo? Tableau says that is an unknown function

Comment: 2019.2.0 .  - 64 - bit

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot update the version of my Tableau atm, therefore I need another way of creating this "ISOWEEKDAY(DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week Number])+"-"+ STR([Year Axis]))) =1"

Comment: See my edited answer.  'iso-weekday' may also be used as an argument in DATEPART function if week start is considered as Monday.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.   But based on your calculation, week 46 and year 2020 is 16/11 when in reality is 09/11 .. See tis doc https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020

Comment: No @Robbie, If you see clearly in that link week1 of 2020 starts from Dec30 instead of 6 Jan as you desired.  Please re-check that this link shows 53 weeks in 2020.  So what is your requirement actually??